# How to wait for a user event to occur in JavaFX elegantly

Tags: javafx, user-input, wait

I am currently writing my own implementation of Tic-Tac-Toe. This is what I am stuck at:

All of my code runs via the

```
  start(Stage stage)
```

method. A part of the code in there handles the events if the user clicks in a specific area on the stage. Basically whenever the user clicks a field

That looks like:

```
   scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

      if(blabla){ // if field is empty
        doBla(); // put X into it
        //...
        }
   }
```

My game loop is as simple as:

```
   while(gameIsFinished == false){

    //Player 1's turn 

    /*Wait until if-statement in the snippet above is executed*/ 

   //Computer's turn

     }
```

I could implement a button that the user has to press after completing his turn. 
I am searching for a more elegant solution though; one that makes the games faster.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Just add the `//Computer's turn` part below `doBla();` (inside the if body)

Comment: Wow yeah. Should have thought about that. Cheers.

Comment: And there is no need to implement a game loop. Just use event handlers and check for "finished' after each move (player and computer).